# How to change the type of a column name in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I read somewhere that Cassandra supports different types for the Column Names unlike RDBMS's out there that supports only Strings.

How do i go about changing the column name of a table in Cassandra?. Or How do i create a table FOO with a Column name as 1985-12-05 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use alter command. Check https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html

but 1985-12-05 won't work as Keyspace, column, and table names created using CQL can only contain alphanumeric and underscore characters.

Comment: So coming back to the question, since Cassandra natively supports having non alphanumeric column names, how do we go about using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Map column type

```
CREATE TABLE FOO(
    id int,
    mymap map<timestamp, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (int));
```

This will serve as dynamic column for you.